# Need help moving the origin to center

Tags: objects

I got a logo in blender and im trying to rotate it 360 degrees. But when i rotated it i realized it isnt centered. I found out that the logo got some invisible edge or something, because when i do "Origin to Geometry" it still isnt in the middle. (Sry for my bad english + second project in blender)

Comment: You could put the 3D cursor where you think the origin should be and transform "Origin to 3D cursor" or parent it to an empty and rotate that (easier to tweak).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use some vertices to find the median point (such diameter, diagonal...), you could follow these steps:
[image]

1. In edit mode, select the vertices to find the median point and press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to move the cursor to selected

[image]

2. In object mode, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to set origin to cursor
   [image]

[image]